Unable to install linux on AMD RYZEN THREADRIPPER PRO 5995WX
I was trying to install Ubuntu (both version 24.04 and 22.04 are tried), the BIOS settings was able to detect the drive I inserted. When I press try to install, the Ubuntu logo is able to show up but after that it is written that "stdin: Invalid argument" "Unable to find a medium container a live file system" as shown in the picture.
I also noticed that when these is shown, my keyboard seems like disconnected from the PC. Anyone can assist on this issue?enter image description here

Did you try this solution already?

Yes I have tried, but it works fine when I try to install on other devices
